# Azure Service Bus Traffic With No Queues Or Topics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We're cleaning up some Azure resources and have come across a service bus that seems to have activity, but doesn't have any queues or topics.  My understanding is that without one or the other of these, you can't send or receive messages.  Is there any way to track down where the requests are coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incoming requests is not just messages. It could also be management operations such as getting namespace information.

Your best bet is to open a support case to understand what's being invoked.